# Conjugacy classes of a group of order $8k$

Tags: group-theory, problem-solving

Let G be a group of order $8k$, show that there are at least 5 different conjugacy classes.

Hi everyone, I have this problem I think I had a solution involving stabilizers, however I feel there must be a really easy and quick solution. Any ideas on what that might be?

Edit: To give more motivation into the question. It was suggested to me by a college, I believe he found it a book by J.M. Gamboa Mutuberría(he has a bunch, I do not know which).
My current line of thought consist of using the fact that considering the action 
$$
\rho:G\times G\rightarrow G, \rho(x,y)=yxy^{-1}
$$
and that $x\in G$ is a fixed point iff $x$ is in the centralizer of $G$ we have $$
card(G)=card(Centr(G))+\sum_{s=1}^{n}\theta_s
$$, where $\theta_1\ldots\theta_n$ are the distinct orbits, now orbits have at least size 2 and divide 8k. But I said before, I think this is getting to complicated and my college suggested the problem must have a simpler suggestion

Comment: The number of finite groups with a given number of conjugacy classes is bounded. (This is due to Landau.) So you can always classify all the groups with at most four conjugacy classes, it's not that hard. Or you can do whatever part of the partial classification is needed to see that the order cannot be divisible by 8.

Comment: @verret Bounded by how much?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Where did you get that equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple answer can be based on the fact that a $2$-group has a non-trivial center (the same applies to any $p$-group). The assumption about the order $n=8k$ of the group $G$ implies by basic Sylow theory that there is a subgroup $P\le G$ of order $8$. Let $z\neq1_G$ be an element of $Z(P)$. It follows that the centralizer of $z$ has order
$8\ell$, $\ell\ge1$. Therefore the conjugacy class of $z$ has $|[z]|=n/(8\ell)\le n/8$
elements.

Assume that there are at most four conjugacy classes — two in addition to $[1]$ and $[z]$. They have sizes $n/a$ and $n/b$ for some divisors $a,b>1$ of $n$. The conjugacy classes form a partition of $G$, so
$$
1+\frac n{8\ell}+\frac n a+\frac n b=n.\qquad(*)
$$
If $a=b=2$ then the left hand side of $(*)$ is too large. If $a,b\ge3$, then the l.h.s. is too small ($1+n/8<n/3$ whenever $n\ge8$). Hence we can assume w.l.o.g. that $a=2$ and $b>2$. Also, $1+n/8\le n/4$ leading to $b\le 4$.

- If $b=4$, then $(*)$ implies that $\ell=1$ and $n=8$. But, a non-abelian group of order eight is either the quaternion group $Q_8$ or the dihedral group $D_4$. Neither has a conjugacy class of size four, so this case can be ruled out.
- If $b=3$, then $(*)$ implies that $\ell=1$ and $n=24$. A conjugacy class of size $n/3$ necessarily consists of elements of order three, each generating its own centralizer. Thus $G$ has four Sylow $3$-subgroups. The conjugation action on the set of those Sylow subgroups gives us a homomorphism $f:G\to S_4$. An element $x\in G$ of order three can normalize only one Sylow $3$-subgroup, namely the one it generates, so $f(x)$ is a 3-cycle. It follows that all the 3-cycles of $S_4$ are in the image of $f$, and those are known to generate $A_4$. Therefore $\operatorname{ker} f$
  has order one or two. The alternative of a kernel of size two is impossible. After all, the kernel is normal, and consists of full conjugacy classes. Hence $f$ is an isomorphism, and $G\cong S_4$. But $S_4$ has five conjugacy classes. A contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

Let $G$ be a finite group with $|G| \equiv 0$ mod $8$ and assume that the number of conjugacy classes is at most $4$. This is equivalent to the statement that the number of *irreducible complex characters* of $G$ is at most $4$. Since $|G|$ is the sum of the squares of its irreducible character degrees we get $|G|=1+a^2+b^2+c^2$, where the $1$ comes from the principal character and $a,b,c$ are non-negative integers. Since squares mod $8$ equal $\bar{0}$,$\bar{1}$ or $\bar{4}$, the equation $\bar{0}=\bar{1}+\bar{a}^2+\bar{b}^2+\bar{c}^2$ mod $8$ has no solutions, a contradiction.

**Note** (1) One can show that if $|G|$ is *odd* and $k(G)$ denotes the number of conjugacy classes, then $|G| \equiv k(G)$ mod $16$.
(2) In general, for a non-abelian $G$,  $k(G) \leq \frac{5}{8}|G|$. Hence if we have equality here, then $|G|$ must be a multiple of $8$. Example: $G=Q_8$, the quaternion group of order $8$.

Comment: Yes correct, the 5/8 theorem is for non-abelian groups of course. Thanks for noting! Will correct. Btw, I gave your direct solution a +1.