# possible class equation for a group of order 8

Tags: group-theory

The exercise is written in the title .

I have found that only $2$ possibilities are there:
$$1+1+2+2+2 \hskip1cm \mbox{ and }\hskip1cm 1+1+4+2;$$
but why does the second not work?

The text does not introduce Sylow's theorem so i would like not to use them if needed.

Comment: There's something not quite right here. Obviously there is a possibility of eight $1$s. But here's a hint: if a class of $x$ has size $4$ then only $e$ and $x$ commute with $x$; now look at the classes of size $1$.

Comment: 1) Your abstract-algebra  tag was too large ; I have changed it into group-theory  2) For those who want to refresh their mind https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Class_equation_of_a_group

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3272336

Answer (score 3):

$1+1$ says that center contains exactly two elements, say $\{1,z\}$.

Appearance of $4$ says, there is an element $x$ with $4$ conjugates, hence its centralizer is of size $8/4=2$.

But, $x$ commutes with itself, as well as central elements $1$ and $z$; so its centralizer should be of size $>2$.

This is a contradiction!

Comment: thank you it was a perfect answer

Comment: The same argument goes through for 1+1+1+1+4